# Beginner help: need help on finding the Matrix A of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the matrix A of the linear transformation T from R2 to R2 that rotates any vector through an angle of 30∘ in the clockwise direction.

Heres what I did so far :
I plugged in 30 into the general matrix
\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\\end{bmatrix}
which turns into this:
\begin{bmatrix}\cos 30&-\sin 30\\\sin 30 &\cos 30 \\\end{bmatrix}
resulting in:

\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}&-\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix}

now, since a clockwise rotation is: \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ -1&0\end{bmatrix}, I set up a matrix multiplication like this and multiplied the two matrices together which ends up with this:

\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}:

However I got it wrong, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

You should not multiply the two matrices together. Your result is essentially firstly rotating counterclockwise by $\pi/6$, then clockwise by $\pi/2$; it ends up with rotating counterclockwise through the angle $\pi/6-\pi/2$.

Instead, note that rotating clockwise $\theta$ is the same as rotating counterclockwise $2\pi-\theta$.

Your "general matrix" is rotating counterclockwise by $\theta$.

Comment: So would my answer be the third matrix listed above?

Comment: @MartinSo: No. "You should not multiply the two matrices together".

Comment: "Your "general matrix" is rotating counterclockwise by θ." do you mean clockwise?

Comment: @MartinSo: no, see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix // or consider the case when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. It rotates the vector $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$.